# How to get stack trace for C/C++ program in CYGWIN environment?

Tags: printing, stack, window, cygwin, trace

**How to get stack trace for C/C++ program in CYGWIN  environment ?**

** I was looking for a back trace mechanism, I've compiled some of the solutions found here and made it a small program for quick reference.

> My Answers with a code snippet:

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN__)

    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <dbghelp.h>
    #include <psdk_inc/_dbg_common.h>
    #include <cxxabi.h>
    #include <cstring>

class Error // Windows version
{
private:

    void *stacktrace[MAX_STACKTRACE_SIZE];
    size_t stacktrace_size;

public:
    const char* message;
    
    Error(const char* m)
        : message(m)
        , stacktrace_size(0)
    {
        // Capture the stack, when error is 'hit'
        stacktrace_size = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, MAX_STACKTRACE_SIZE, stacktrace, nullptr);
    }

    void print_backtrace(ostream& out) const
    {
        SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
        HANDLE         process;
        size_t         length;
        process = GetCurrentProcess();

        SymInitialize(process, nullptr, TRUE);

        symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO *)calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
        symbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
        symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        length = strlen (symbol->Name);
        std::string result;
        char tempStr[255] = {0};
        
        for (int i = 0; i < stacktrace_size; i++)
        {
            int status = 0; 
            // '_' is missing in symbol->Name , hence prefix it and concat with symbol->Name
            char prefixed_symbol [256] = "_" ;
        
            SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(stacktrace[i]), 0, symbol);

            auto backtrace_line = string(symbol->Name);
            if (backtrace_line.size() == 0) continue;
        
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling
            // Prefix '_' with symbol name, so that __cxa_demangle does the job correctly
            // $ c++filt -n _Z9test_ringI12SmallIntegerIhEEvRK4RingIT_E
            
            strcat (prefixed_symbol, symbol->Name);
            
            char * demangled_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(prefixed_symbol, nullptr, nullptr, &status);
            
            if(status < 0)
            {
                sprintf(tempStr, "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", stacktrace_size-i-1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address);
                // out <<  symbol->Name << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(tempStr, "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", stacktrace_size - i - 1, demangled_name, symbol->Address);
                // out << demangled_name << endl;
            }
            // Append the extracted info to the result
            result += tempStr;
                        
            // Free the HEAP allocation made by __cxa_demangle
            free((void*)demangled_name);
            
            // Restore the prefix '_' string
            prefixed_symbol [1] = '\0';
        }
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
        free(symbol);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    try {
     
     do_something ();
     if (false == status) throw Error("SystemError");
    }
   catch (const Error &error)
   {
        cout << "NotImplementedError(\"" << error.message << "\")" << endl;
        error.print_backtrace(cout);
        return 1;
        
   }

#endif
```

***Command Line Option:***

// Use -limagehlp to link the library
g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp -limagehlp

Comment: It seems you are mixing Cygwin and Windows; why ?  In Cygwin for tracing System call you can use `strace`

Comment: Yes, I've gcc/g++ running in CYGWIN environment in Windows. The need is to capture the program call stack at the time of exception.